# How to sum values across a set of categories, in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get a list of category items and display the total amount linked to those categories. I have the "amount" field in the "transaction" table and I want to link it to category table.

This is how my tables are:

1. Category Master
2. Subcategory Master
3. Item Master
4. Transaction

So to get my "Amount" field to category, I would have to pass a certain common column between them. I have CategoryID in SubCategory master, subcatid in item master and similarly itemid in transaction.

Earlier when I grouped the amount using transaction date, the process went smoothly:

`SELECT TransactionDate, SUM(Amount) FROM transaction GROUP BY MONTH(TransactionDate)`

Now the problem I'm facing with grouping it using categoryname is that all of the amount seems to be =50 whereas it is still different in the database. I know that this is something really silly, but I am comparatively new to programming and not sure how to use logic appropriately.

```
    SELECT categorymaster.CategoryName, transaction.Amount
    FROM categorymaster
    INNER JOIN subcategorymaster
    INNER JOIN itemmaster
    INNER JOIN transaction
    GROUP BY categorymaster.CategoryName
```

Comment: Did you try specifying ON with all your foreign keys?

Comment: work on editing this question.  Post your actual code, some sample data and intended result given that sample data.  shortening your code makes all of us just look at it and wonder did he forget the on conditions, didn't do a aggregation on amount....  Or in your SELECT transactionDate, GROUP BY Month() that shouldn't even be a valid statement because transactiondate would have to be in group by.  However SELECT MOINT(TransactionDate) would..... to may unknowns for anyone to help you troubleshoot effectively

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your primary key in each table is named "ID".  You didn't provide that info.

```
SELECT categorymaster.CategoryName, sum(transaction.Amount)
  FROM categorymaster
       INNER JOIN subcategorymaster 
             ON subcagetorymaster.CategoryId = categorymaster.ID
       INNER JOIN itemmaster
             ON itemmaster.SubCatId = subcategorymaster.ID
       INNER JOIN transaction
             ON transaction.ItemId = itemmaster.ID
GROUP BY categorymaster.CategoryName
```

Comment: You're a life savior. @stonegiant